# i have this error when when i try to build my app in flutter

Tags: database, flutter, svg

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nQKOx.png)

Error: Type 'AssetBundle' not found.
AssetBundle? bundle

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the problem is related to your database. The error comes from flutter_svg. Did you add a proper asset route in the end of your pubspec?
Like this:

flutter:
uses-material-design: true

assets:
- assets/images/intro/

Comment: yes i added it properly

Answer (score 0):

This problem is not related to your persistant database, it's an error coming from the [`flutter_svg`](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_svg) package you have installed. According to the issue [#610](https://github.com/dnfield/flutter_svg/issues/610), all you have to do is update Flutter to at least `2.5.0`, to do this, run the following command in your terminal:

`flutter upgrade`

Comment: my flutter is  ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

Answer (score 0):

This is a very difficult problem. Barely solved it. I found only one solution to it, no one showed anything sensible.

In the Terminal in Android Studio (Android Studio: `View -> Tool Windows -> Terminal`. Old: Go to `Tools -> Open Terminal`, or see at the bottom of the Android Studio path `"Terminal"`) you need to write just **`upgrade --force`**

This removes all issues under clean and reinstalls Flutter. Better than this way to solve the problem - **it is impossible.**